# Custom compare string method throwing indexarrayoutofbounds

Tags: java

I have a custom compare method:

```
public int compareStrings(String one, String two) {
    int compareAmount = 0;
    if (one.length() == two.length()) {
        compareAmount++;
    } else {
        compareAmount--;
    }
    int x = 0;
    for (char i : one.toCharArray()) {
        if (!(x > two.length())) {
            if (two.charAt(x) == i) {
                compareAmount++;
            }
            x++;
        }
    }
    return compareAmount;
}
```

If string one is "Ok" and String two is "Lets give it a go" it throws java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2. I cannot see were I've gone wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going all the way to `two.length()` instead of stopping at `two.length() - 1`. This doesn't work since arrays are indexed from `0..length()-1`.
Just change your `if` condition inside the loop to fix the problem:

```
if (!(x >= two.length())) {
```

Comment: Although you might answer the question, this does not help the person who is asking to get better at programming in general

Comment: @David: I respectfully disagree. I think OP learned something about arrays here, which should be helpful in the future.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. My apology

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the String two is 11, the last index is 10. You're just checking if x is NOT greater than the length of two. But it might be equal which is out of bounds. Just change it to >=

Answer (score 0):

Dude, first of all, don't reimplement this kind of algorithms.

Use the compareTo(String) method defined in the String class.

You can also learn from the JDKs source code and see how they implement this method http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l1096

If you need a custom comparator for a specific class, you must implement  the Comparator interface.

If you are starting to learn java and want to get good at it. At least make a full read of the official Java tutorial by oracle

Comment: I used the compareTo method but found it unreilable.. It returned strange results for me.

Comment: Provide examples of how 'strange' is. I am 100% sure the build in functions for string does work as expected.